# Escape sequence not working in oracle 10g driver

Tags: c, oracle, data-binding, oracle10g, nls-lang

I am connecting oracle 11g database through C code. I am using oracle 10g driver for DB connection.

Query failed with error code 1461.

When I try to insert string : 'I am in ' Mumbai ' ' ===> It failed.
I tried: 'I am in 'Mumbai' ' ===>It was successful. (I think space between ' and Mumbai is causing problem.

Same result after using escape character in string:
When I try to insert string : 'I am in '' Mumbai '' '=====> It failed.
I tried: 'I am in ''Mumbai'' ' ===> It was successful.

I am using same NLS language character on my PC and Database.
Same setup is working fine with oracle 11g driver.

Is there any way to fix it through setup rather than string manipulation?

Comment: Its not duplicate question. I tried using single quotes twice but it fails when it has space character between.

Comment: DBBindParameter( 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_CHAR, "I am in ''mumbai''" ) ;  
Data binding is successful. It fails in Insert query in C code.